# Changing row values until a particular row is appeared on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a solution to changing row values until a particular row is appeared.

For example, here is a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_val' : [0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'on&off' : [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]
    })  
           
Out[11] df
   ts_val  on&off
0       0       0
1       0       0
2      -1       1 #starting point
3      -1       0
4      -1       0
5      -1       0
6       0       1 #end point
7       0       0
8       0       1 #starting point 2
9       0       0
10      0       1 #end point 2
```

On above dataframe, I want to replace row of `df['on&off']` as *1* untill another *1* is appeared on the `df['on&off']`

In more detail, on the example, *1* is appeared on `df['on&off'][2]` which is a starting point, and another *1* which is end point is appeared on the `df['on&off'][6]`. I need to replace the value to *1* between `df['on&off'][2:6]`.

Such as, this *dataframe* :

```
   ts_val  on&off
0       0       0
1       0       0
2      -1       1
3      -1       1
4      -1       1
5      -1       1
6       0       1
7       0       0
8       0       1
9       0       1
10      0       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following snippet - create groups by cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), get groups contains `1` in original column with all unpair values, filter them to variable `groups` and set only filtered groups to `1`:

```
s = df['on&off'].cumsum()
m = (s % 2).eq(1) & df['on&off'].eq(1)

groups = s[m]

df.loc[s.isin(groups), 'on&off'] = 1
print (df)

# Output:

    ts_val  on&off
0        0       0
1        0       0
2       -1       1
3       -1       1
4       -1       1
5       -1       1
6        0       1
7        0       0
8        0       1
9        0       1
10       0       1
```

EDIT:

If last `1` is missing, so last group is not complete and this group cannot be processed solution is:

```
#tested solution with pair `1`s
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_val' : [0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'on&off' : [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]
    })  
           
s = df['on&off'].cumsum()
m1 = (s % 2).eq(1) & df['on&off'].eq(1)
m2 = (s % 2).eq(0) & df['on&off'].eq(1)

groups1 = s[m1]
groups2 = s.shift()[m2]

groups = set(groups1) & set(groups2)
print (groups)
{1.0, 3.0}

df.loc[s.isin(groups), 'on&off'] = 1
print (df)
    ts_val  on&off
0        0       0
1        0       0
2       -1       1
3       -1       1
4       -1       1
5       -1       1
6        0       1
7        0       0
8        0       1
9        0       1
10       0       1
```

---

```
#last 1 is removed, so only one group
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts_val' : [0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'on&off' : [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0]
    })  
           
s = df['on&off'].cumsum()
m1 = (s % 2).eq(1) & df['on&off'].eq(1)
m2 = (s % 2).eq(0) & df['on&off'].eq(1)

groups1 = s[m1]
groups2 = s.shift()[m2]

groups = set(groups1) & set(groups2)
print (groups)
{1.0}

df.loc[s.isin(groups), 'on&off'] = 1
print (df)
    ts_val  on&off
0        0       0
1        0       0
2       -1       1
3       -1       1
4       -1       1
5       -1       1
6        0       1
7        0       0
8        0       1
9        0       0
10       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have basically used a flag to track the start and end points. The df.shape
gives the row and column count.

```
flag = 1
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
  if df['on&off'].iloc[i] == 1 and flag == 1:
    flag = 0
  elif df['on&off'].iloc[i] == 0 and flag == 0:
    df['on&off'].iloc[i] = 1
  elif df['on&off'].iloc[i] == 1 and flag == 0:
    flag = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. using itertools cycle
2. using the walrus operator :=
3. using := in the tuple to switch the state of d and but only using the 1st value in the tuple.

Code:

```
c = itertools.cycle([0,1])
d = next(c)
df['on&off1'] = [(1,(d:= next(c)))[0] if df.loc[i,'on&off']==1 
    else d for i in range(len(df))]
```

Output:

[image]